# Getting a format exception parsing a string to a double

Tags: c#

So there are still some logic errors in this that I am working on. I'm not worried about those, and I want to figure them out myself.

I'm working on a slot machine app for some independent study and when I try to parse the value of the label that shows the players cash into a variable I am getting a format exception. How do fix this and more importantly why am I getting this exception?

I have also tried using `TryParse` and `Convert.ToDouble`.

```
protected void PullBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get players cash//////////////////////////////
    double playersCash = Convert.ToDouble(playerMoneyLBL.Text);

    // Other way I tried that didn't work ////////////
    //double playersCash = 0;
    //double.TryParse(playerMoneyLBL.Text.Trim(), out playersCash);

    // Get players bet /////////////////////////////
    double playerBet = 0;
    if (!double.TryParse(betTB.Text, out playerBet))
        return;

   // Spin the slots//////////////////////////////
   Image1.ImageUrl = spinReel();
   Image2.ImageUrl = spinReel();
   Image3.ImageUrl = spinReel();

    // Find multiplier //////////////////////////////
    double multiplier = findMultiplier();

    // Find winnings ///////////////////////////////
    double winnnings = multiplier * playerBet;
    playerMoneyLBL.Text = (playersCash + winnnings).ToString();

    // Add winnings to players money //////////////
    playerMoneyLBL.Text = (playersCash + winnnings).ToString();
}
```

Comment: which line gives the error. Dont just post complete code

Comment: the one right below the get player cash comment

Comment: Care to remove the irrelevant code, most probably this line `double playersCash = Convert.ToDouble(playerMoneyLBL.Text);` causing the error use `TryParse` instead for `Convert.To...`

Comment: if you look in the comment below that line you can see the way i tried to use tryparse and still got the error. is there something wrong with the way i tried to implement that? also is that better for the irrelevant code or should i just remove the rest of the block?

Comment: Make sure the user isn't entering the dollar sign.  Also trim may help : Convert.ToDouble(playerMoneyLBL.Text.Trim());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here.

```
playerMoneyLBL.Text = "$100";
```

As you have `$` in-front of 100, you cannot convert that to float. Make it something like this.

```
double playersCash = Convert.ToDouble(playerMoneyLBL.Text.substring(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

double.Parse uses your CurrentCulture settings on the current environment by default.

```
double d = double.Parse("Your Text Here", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or if you want it more secure way, try:

```
value = "Your String";
style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol| NumberStyles.AllowThousands;
culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
if (Double.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
{
   // Write your code for true condition
}
else
{
  // Write your code for false condition
}
```